# Invertibility of a system with a median filter

Tags: median-filter

I know is that for a system to be invertible it should be mapping one-one, but what happens in this signal?, I feel like I need to know the value of $x[n]$ before.

$y[n]= \mathrm{median}\{x[n-1],x[n],x[n+1]\}$

Answer (score 5):

Consider a signal $x$ such that $x(n) = x_0$ for almost every $n$, but for every 10$^{th}$ sample $x(n) = 100 x_0$.  Then a median filter will return $y(n) = x_0$ *always*.

You can change the value of that "every tenth sample" in any way you want: let it equal $x_0 - 100$, $\pi$, $42$, whatever, and the result is the same.

Because the results are *all the same* when you have *different* inputs, you cannot reconstruct the input from the output -- this is the essence of the filter being non-invertible.

Comment: rackin' up that rep, Tim.  You'll be whizzing past me in no time, flat.

Comment: Regardless of what StackExchange may think, I don't consider it a contest.  I just answer interesting questions as best as I can.

Comment: I'm kind of amused by the fact that I spend a lot more work hours doing DSP than circuit design, yet I have way more points over on electronics.stackexchange.com than I do here.

Comment: I am afraid that if an input value is 42, the filter should spit out this value, always

Comment: i don't consider this to be a contest either.  but i notice when someone i know from the *comp.dsp* days shows up and immediately is useful.  i sorta peetered out on both forums.